# Failed to create a directory: ./logs\train; No such file or directory [Op:CreateSummaryFileWriter

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0

I am working on VMMR dataset and I am getting this error while starting training callback for the model.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, TensorBoard, CSVLogger
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers, models
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import applications
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import math
top_layers_file_path="top_layers.iv3.hdf5"

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(top_layers_file_path, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, 
              mode='min')
tb = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs', batch_size=val_flow.batch_size, write_graph=True, update_freq='batch')
early = EarlyStopping(monitor="loss", mode="min", patience=5)
csv_logger = CSVLogger('./logs/iv3-log.csv', append=True)

history = model.fit_generator(train_flow, epochs=5, verbose=1,validation_data=val_flow,
                              validation_steps=math.ceil(val_flow.samples/val_flow.batch_size),
                              steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(train_flow.samples/train_flow.batch_size),
                              callbacks=[checkpoint, early, tb, csv_logger]
```

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: I am using windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your platform is windows,Try this

```
log_dir='.\logs'
```

and creating folder manually should always work